# Replace a certain character in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Am currently running this script (the original author is no longer supporting it):

http://askthecssguy.com/articles/checkbox-filters-with-jquery/

This works fine apart from if you have a tag (these in tern make each of the check boxes) which has spaces in it (if you have spaces it creates multiple tags). The only way to get around this is by using underscores which is fine however looks rubbish on the rendered page. I was wondering is there a way after this script is run to remove all `_` from certain `<li>` classes and replace them with a space " ".
Sorry if this is confusing!

Comment: do you know every class you want to replace?

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(".filters li label").each(
    function(){
        var elem = jQuery(this);
        var txt = elem.html();
        if(txt.indexOf("_")>-1){
            elem.html( txt.replace(/_/g," ") );
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: hey i tried this but it didn't work - i changed the class names and added it under the other jquery. 

I was wonderting though, I found this in the code:

$('.filterThis > li').each( function (i) {
  var thisClassString = $(this).attr('class');
  stringOfClassNames = stringOfClassNames +''+ thisClassString
 });

// now i have a space-delimited string of all class names stored
// in the stringOfClassNames variable.

Is there a way to make it not do space delimitated?

Comment: HUH? What does class name have to do with the underscore? Build an example page to work with.

Comment: It needs to be running with the tag code. The JavaScript needs to run after the tags are generated.

Comment: your code above? Do i include it at the end of the html page?

Comment: Line 6 has a typo - `elm.html` should probably be `elem.html`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your list item elements have a class "tagFilter" applied. Then you can do the following to remove underscores from the text of the list item:

```
$('.tagFilter').each(function(i,v) {
    this.innerText = this.innerText.replace(/_/g, ' ');
});
```

Note, however, this assumes that your list item doesn't contain any other child nodes except a text node. That is:

```
<li class="tagFilter">my_tag_with_spaces</li>
```

If you have a specific child element of the list item that contains the text, say a label element, then you can do:

```
$('.tagFilter label').each(function(i,v) {
    this.innerText = this.innerText.replace(/_/g, ' ');
});
```

Comment: I think the problem is that this is what the list elements look like:
<ul class="filterThis"> 
 <li class="others_one"> </li>
</ul>

And the script generates the check box label from the class name.

Comment: My reply is a generic answer based on the question as it is framed. I did not waste a lot of time digging into how the plugin works or even what it does. All you need to do is change the selectors in my answer to fit your situation.